# How do I extract a number from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, numbers, extract

I have the following string in Python.

```
"My number is 5"
```

How can I check to see if a string contains a number and subsequently extract it, thus giving me the string "5"?

Edit: By using the re module, I'm now getting the result [u,'5']. How can I get the number 5 out of this result?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use regex:

```
import re
my_num = re.findall("\d+","my number is 5")
```

`\d+` match 1 or more occurence of [0-9]

demo to extract the number from 0-20:

```
>>> a ="my string may 0-20, but how to remove number like 30,22 etc"
>>> my_num = re.findall('\d+',a)
>>> [int(x) for x in my_num if int(x)<=20]
[0, 20]
```

Comment: Okay. And what about higher numbers? I need to check for digits ranging from 0 - 20.

Comment: plz provide all information in ur question. like expected input, expected output and wt u tried so far

Comment: plz add comment for downvote, so one can correct